# SVG Animation throws a 'Cannot read property 'style' of null' error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

My issue is the building of an SVG arch that expands upon scrolling: [image]

I build a React component that is supposed to get the job done:

```
function Arch() {

let arch = document.querySelector("#arch") 
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () { 
let value = window.scrollY; 
arch.style.backgroundSize = 100 + value*2 +'px'; 
});

return (
    <div id="arch" className="arch" style={{backgroundSize:'50'}} ></div>
    )
}
```

but while I can see the SVG animation taking place for a second, the application throws an error: Cannot read property 'style' of null immediately upon reaching the section of the arch component:

[image]

I understand that 'style'  is returning null, but I don't understand why.

Comment: A quick fix would be to move your `let arch = document.querySelector("#arch") ` inside the event handler. Your problem is that your `querySelector()` is being run before the element has been rendered to the page, so it's returning `undefined`. You may well have other issues once that's fixed though because the second your `Arch` component gets rerendered it's going to start flickering or will just reset to the initial `backgroundSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ref to access and modify DOM nodes in React.

Check https://www.newline.co/@dmitryrogozhny/how-to-access-dom-nodes-in-react-with-refs--57d97b3d

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html